# Confused about index partition vs index replicas

Tags: search

Trying to fix something in our environment and I am still confused about this.
Our QA environment has 4 servers, 2wfe, and   2 app servers.

We noticed that the people who installed it, made it with 4 partitions in the 2 WFEs.

I dont have a real screenshot here but it looks like this:
https://communities.netapp.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/38-13142-23907/620-228/SearchIdx_5.png

but with 4 columns,

If I read the best practices, it says to add index partitions for each 10M items.
Does it make sense to have the same index partitions across al servers?

Can someone clarify the difference between both and normally how they should be setup? My best guess is that an index partition is phyisical 1/nth of the entire index, and it should be split across several servers, right?

Why having more than 1 index partition with a farm that only has 800,000 searchable items?

Comment: unfortunately the screenshot is not available anymore. could you reupload and post directly to stackexchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a try. An index replica is a copy of the index. This is commonly used for availability. For example, create a replica of the index on more than one server so that your queries can be served by more than one server. The whole index is copied.

A partition is a chunk of the index. As you indicate, create a new partition for scale, the recommendation is 10M items. So if you are indexing a lot of content you may create multiple partitions.

The fun comes when you wish to do both, scale and HA. Now you have multiple replicas of multiple partitions, across multiple servers. For a farm with less than 1M items, I would create index replicas but not partitions.

I review a lot of this in my class on Pluralsight: [SharePoint Search Back to Front](http://bit.ly/abSearch)

Comment: index partitions are created in the same server right?, and in powershell you need to define the rootdirectory for each index partition, so if I have 10M items, and 4 index partitions in one server then each index partition will have 25% of the content, but maybe I dont understand correctly, but why would I have index partitions on the same server and same disk? if the drive is damaged all is lost, shouldnt index partitions be across diferent disks?

Comment: I can't explain why it was done like that in your farm. Usually you would have partitions on separate servers. You can also use separate disks, but partitions are not an HA strategy, they are generally used for performance.

Comment: so, replicas are for HA(in different servers) and partitions are done for better query performance (also in different servers)

Comment: Partitions are done for scale because the index files associated with a 10M document index can be huge.